# Which is the correct option?

Tags: tense

This question I am confused with (which is the correct option?)

Choose the correct answer form a, b, c, or d:

> Do you think I could borrow the book after you  ......... reading it?
>
> a. had finished
>   b. finished
>   c. have finished
>   d. will finish

I know *have finished reading* is the most correct according to tense sequence, but the present perfect is hardly used to tell about a finished completed action (all grammar books tell that).

If we say *have finished reading it* is this telling about a completed action ?

Comment: *have finished* (or *are finished*) would be correct and idiomatic.

Comment: After you are finished  ? why passive ? not possible I see and it is not mentioned among the choices ) ... Also, I can say :  after you finish reading  it ... It looks better than to say : ( after you have finished reading it), but this also is not mentioned among the choices.

Comment: I know ( have finished reading ) is the most suggested one, but the present perfect is hardly to tell about a finished completed action and here it is behind the logic >>> How someone lends you a book if he still reads it ... ?

Comment: "After you are finished ? why passive ?" It's not passive ("The book was finished by you") it's using the past participle as a descriptive modifier (like an adjective). Another, similar phrasing would be *after you are through reading it*.

Comment: "the present perfect is hardly to tell about a finished completed action and here it is behind the logic >>> How someone lends you a book if he still reads it ... ?" I don't understand what you are saying, sorry.

Comment: I don't understand why you think the action can persist to the present time if you use 'have **finished** reading'. Can it be that you confuse it with 'have **been** reading'? In 'have finished reading' 'reading' is a noun - it represents the reading action. You could enhance it to 'have finished your (action of) reading'. You see clearly that the reading is finished. Not so if you take 'have been reading'. Here 'reading' is kind of an adjective and means 'in the state of reading'. So, it means 'have been in the state of reading'. It obviously doesn't say anything about the end of that state.

Comment: In other words, the statment you'd like to build doesn't contain a progressive/continuous tense as 'reading' is not part of the verb. It's a simple tense. If we get rid of the politeness the statement goes 'Do you think I _can_ borrow...?'. It's the present tense. But what is the nearest 'past' to the present tense? The present perfect tense - actions (e.g. reading of something) which have just finished. That's why it's correct to say 'Do you think I can borrow the book now that/after you have finished (reading) it?' 'to finish it' and 'to finish reading it' is the same regarding the tense.

Comment: When the person gets to the end of the book, they will say "I have finished reading it. Now I can lend it to my friend."

Comment: The question ( topic ) is not mine  I picked online I also agree to use the perfect ( have finished according to tenses sequence )  present simple  >>> present simple \ simple future \ present perfect    OK ...  On the other hand I just ask how it could be possible in such a situation we  mentioned above  (  You want someone gives you a book ) and perhaps its owner has not completed reading it yet.  I see the present perfect does not tell about a finished action.   Do you think that the man ( owner of the book ) really finished reading it , so that you can borrow from him ?

Comment: OK , I know simple tense ... Could is used for a polite request .... My question is about the perfect ( have finished reading ) how it is possible ?

Comment: When the person gets to the end of the book, they will say "I have finished reading it. Now I can lend it to my friend." – Kate Bunting  according to the present perfect, are you sure its owner finished reading it ?

Comment: I know ( have been reading = present perfect continuous  is not the same as have finished reading ..  also the the present perfect sometimes does the same or also it is not used for a completed action this is mentioned in all books of grammar.

Comment: #suggestion: I think the man is not sure of the book's owner will allow him to borrow the book, so in this case the present perfect is useful. Mainly said at the beginning ( Do you think ) = not sure

Comment: We can use the present perfect even if we are sure the book's owner will allow us to borrow the book; in your last comment you're inventing imaginary rules of grammar.

Comment: In addition to uncompleted actions, the present perfect is used for completed actions in the recent past and completed actions that are relevant to the present. [See this website.](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-use.html) We want to borrow the book shortly after you have finished reading it, so we're talking about a (future) recent action, and so we can use the present perfect.

Comment: I told you my opinion to satisfy or not, the issue is yours.  80 % of cases the present perfect is to indicate uncompleted action. Yes with these : this month \ this year \ several times etc... I have been to Europe = went and returned =  done ( I know all these rules ) I think you did not get or read my comment (  suggestion)  One question I asked you, you come and bring examples are not the same of the topic, Of course anything should be according to the context. One thing else to tell you only with ( just) the activity can be finished  I have just finished my work = recently I finished

Comment: @Mohammad Ahmad: Could you please give us a simple example of a sentence where present perfect does **not** express a finished action or a finished series of actions? Please give us a sentence where the action in present perfect is still ongoing while speaking the sentence. It should be no problem if it's like that in 80% of all cases. Please consider that a **possible** continuation does **not** make the action **ongoing**.

Comment: @BenA: "I've lived in Massachusetts for ten years" strongly implies that I'm still living there. But on the other hand "I've walked the dog" strongly implies that I've brought him back from the walk.

Comment: @PeterShor: The ten years worth of living ***is*** complete. It’s the eleventh year that is now in progress.

Comment: @BenA:  You mentioned good examples (  use present perfect \ not finished actions)  Actually the present perfect is like a bridge joining between the past and present, thus we cannot use the present perfect with expressions of ( finished action)  last week \ yesterday \ last month \ last year ... But we can say ( since yesterday ) = starting point

Comment: @BenA :  with the verb ( think ) = one is not sure of the result  ( not guaranteed )  I think it will be rainy today = I Just expect  >> I see the clouds and would say : surely it is going to rain = 100 % expectation  ( there is evidence )  >> When I say : Do you think I could borrow the book after you have finished reading it. Perhaps one day \ two days \ month etc.. he still reads on and I wait  = I am not sure he will give me the book within a few seconds or a few hours, but I hope on him giving me the book just he finished reading it

Answer (score 1):

(I am going to refer to the comments to your question as well.)

'but the present perfect is *hardly used* to tell about a finished completed action (all grammar books tell that).'

Please have a look at [Present Perfect](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-use.html). Do you still have the impression of *hardly used*?

The sense of continuity is added to the present perfect tense *only* if we use it with 'for' resp. 'since'. Well, we're neither asking
*'Do you think I could borrow the book after you have finished reading it for two weeks?'* (a spark of sense in it)
nor are we asking
*'Do you think I could borrow the book after you have finished reading it since today?'* (complete nonsense).

That's why we refer to a *finished/completed* action here.

By the way, we should also consider the assumed length of 'to finish'. While we can easily say 'I have read the book for three months (now).' saying 'I have finished reading the book for three months.' sounds strange because *finishing* is about coming to an end - unlike *living*. Therefore, 'I have finished reading the book.' excludes a continuation of the finishing act in the same way as 'He has died.' excludes a continuation of dying - unlike 'I have lived in London.' where living in London can continue.

In addition, the 'do you think' question reveals no uncertainty of temporal kind and is therefore irrelevant for our consideration of the finishedness of the reading act resp. of the present perfect tense. The whole question is not interested in the exact time the act of borrowing could happen. It *solely* expresses uncertainty caused by possibly existing factors which could render the act of borrowing impossible although the book is theoretically 'borrowable' because the reading is (definitely) finished - factors like the wish to read the book once again or the promise to borrow it to someone else. Of cause, the inquirer wants to have the book as soon as possible. But saying '*after* you have finished reading it', they submit to the reading pace of the book owner and, thus, accept the temporal uncertainty *in the first place*.

Comment: Well I read all the examples of a finished action using the present perfect and none of the examples is similar to the one I asked about : 
I have been to Tokyo.  Yes I mentioned  = went + returned = 100 % finished action
They have visited Paris three times. three times ? does it need a proof ?
We have never seen that film. OK clear finished action 
3: With an unfinished time word (this month, this week, today). The period of time is still continuing.
I haven't seen her this month.  have never seen  Can I guess the opposite ?

Comment: Have a second look at the chart. Present perfect describes finished actions even if an unfinished time word is used. 'I haven't seen her this month' is a finished action because it only refers to the time from the start of the month to the time of speaking. It doesn't matter that the whole referred period hasn't yet come to an end. Once again, present perfect is used predominantly (not hardly) to tell about finished actions. 'I have never seen her before' is exactly the same. The referred period ends at the time of speaking. Your example neither contains 'for' nor 'since'. So, finished action.